# Подстановка в шаблон Word проблема с ZipArchive

Tags: php, phpword

Делаю подстановку данных клиента в шаблон документа используябиблиотеку [phpword](https://phpword.codeplex.com/). Все делаю по примеру.

Код простой:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPWord.php';
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Template.docx');
$document->setValue('d_num', '777');
$document->setValue('d_date', '04.10.2014');
$document->setValue('last_name', 'Никоненко');
$document->setValue('name', 'Сергей');
$document->setValue('surname', 'Васильевич');
$document->save('Template_full.docx');
?>
```

Но скрипт не работает выдает ошибку

```
AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /var/www/***/data/www/***/php/phpWord_demo/PHPWord/Template.php on line 71
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не подключена библиотека Zip

Comment: в самом php надо установить?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/zip.installation.php